# Opencart Ajax quickcheckout , how to implement a new action when confirm order button is clicked

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

Im trying to implement an SMS verification of order to ajax quickcheckout in opencart.
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15580

The extension is working fine on the default checkout template. Which pop ups a window to enter the code received. when the correct code is entered the checkout function is complete and order is placed.
But, what do i have to do if i want to make it work with AJAX quick checkout.
I have provided the vQmod xml file which is for default template and i need that to work wiht the ajax checkout.

Here is the vQmod xml for sms verification module. Default checkout.

```
<modification>

<id><![CDATA[sms-confirmation-of-payment-methods-oc2-extension]]></id>
<version><![CDATA[3.2.0]]></version>
<author><![CDATA[dev@smshare.fr - http://www.smshare.fr]]></author>
<vqmver><![CDATA[2.5.1]]></vqmver>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/checkout.tpl">

    <operation info="Intercept clicks on the button that validate payment method choice">
        <search position="before" offset="1"><![CDATA[url: 'index.php?route=checkout/confirm',]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[

    var wait_for_confirmation = false;

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url  : 'index.php?route=checkout/smshare_scpm/payment_method_chosen', 
        type : 'post',            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json['scpm_code_status']);
            if(json['scpm_code_status'] === 'scpm_code_sent'){

                wait_for_confirmation = true;

                //show the popup to confirm the code.
                //$.magnificPopup.open({
                //    modal: true,
                //    items: {
                //        src: '#smshare-popup', // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
                //        type: 'inline'
                //    }
                //});

                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    modal: true,
                    items: {
                        src: 'index.php?route=checkout/smshare_scpm/load_popup_content',
                        type: 'ajax'
                    }
                });  
            }
        }
    });

    if(wait_for_confirmation) return;

        ]]></add>
    </operation>

</file>


<file name="catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php">

    <operation info="Inject somewhere popup scripts">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[

        //SCPM: popup
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/smshare/popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js');
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/smshare/popup/magnific-popup.css');

        //SCPM: ladda
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/smshare/ladda/spin.min.js');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/smshare/ladda/ladda.min.js');
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/smshare/ladda/ladda-themeless.min.css');

        ]]></add>
    </operation>

</file>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

For order SMS I have done this before. Rather using JavaScript solution go with Native opencart solution.

```
catalog/model/checkout/order.php
```

Under `addOrderHistory` funciton

look for following line

```
// If order status is 0 then becomes greater than 0 send main html email
if (!$order_info['order_status_id'] && $order_status_id) {
```

After this this line call your method

May be like this

```
$this->load->model('module/sms');   
$this->model_module_sms->on_order_add($order_id, $order_info['total']);
```

I do not recommend modify original files directly. use vqmod instead.

Comment: Im not looking for order sms notifications. I want my customers to receive an SMS to verify their order. Take a look at Sms confirmation of payment methods in opencart extensions.